# How to use ISNULL on multiple fields in a Infromatica filter condition?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have scenario where i have to check for the null values in multiple fields based on that i informatica should whether to load the record into target or not.

Example: I have col1, col2,col3,col4 fields. If any of these fields isnull then ignore that record else load the record.

Please suggest me how to approach this scenario.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Create an expression with an output field named e.g. `ToBeRemoved` with the following expression:

```
DECODE(TRUE,
ISNULL(col1), 1,
ISNULL(col2), 1,
ISNULL(col3), 1,
...
ISNULL(colN), 1,
0)
```

Next use a filter with a condition `ToBeRemoved=0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all the fields, if the result is null it means that at least one column is null:

`NOT ISNULL(col1||col2||col3||col4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below condition in filter/ router,

```
 ISNULL(col1) OR
 ISNULL(col2) OR
 ISNULL(col3) OR
 ISNULL(col4)
```

This is a cost effective approach with respect to performance.